# Raster calculator error 000867

Tags: arcgis-pro, raster-calculator

So I am trying to convert DEM values from meters to feet using `Raster Calculator`. But I keep on getting error `000867` `contains invalid cell size or dataset.`.

I tried exporting the input raster as a tif to a local drive and then do the conversion but get same error.
I tried exporting the output raster a tif to a local drive but still get the same error.

How can I fix this in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: OneDrive was the issue. Saving the project and the data to a local/network drive solves the issue.

Comment: [ArcGIS Pro and Cloud Storage Services](https://support.esri.com/en-us/knowledge-base/problem-arcgis-pro-and-cloud-storage-services-000025605)